# How can I include a custom command in deb file, to be executed at the end of installation?

Tags: dpkg, deb, debian

Well, I like to mark **/usr/bin/program.sh** as executable using following command:

> chmod +x /usr/bin/program.sh

I want the above command to be executed at the **end of installation of the Debian package.**

Is there a painless way to inject the command into the deb?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `dpkg-deb` to extract the .deb file

Create a temp dir

```
mkdir temp
```

Extract the .deb file to temp directory

```
dpkg-deb -x file.deb temp/
cd temp/
dpkg-deb -e file.deb
```

Now change the **DEBAIN/postinst** file. This script be called right after the installation of package. So add the code which is needed for you.

Rebuild the package

```
dpkg-deb -b . file.deb
```

or

If you don't want to edit .deb file. Create a simple shell script to call the .deb and the command you want to run.

```
vi test.sh
dpkg -i file.deb
/usr/bin/program.sh
```

and run it as `./test.sh`

Hope this helps